# postgis, mapserver & openlayers: if data is not in table give an error / pop-up

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis, mapserver, query

I have created a website with postgis, mapserver & openlayers. 
On the website you can enter a postal code and then a drivetime isochroon is created.

The problem now is that you can enter anything in the input box. If you enter a postal code that does not exist (or maybe some letters) nothing happens. No isochron is created, which is correct because it is not a valid code.

What I want is that if you enter a not existing postal code I would like to have a pop-up (or something like that) which says: 'this is not an existing postal code, please enter another postal code'

Someone any idea how I can create this?

The website is: [maps.geodan.nl/reistijden.htm](http://maps.geodan.nl/reistijden.htm)

Thanks, Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some ways to solve your problem. the main solution is that @Kurt Overberg' answer as controlling before sendining any data. the other ways which come to my mind are

- you can control your respond whether any data return or not. if not empty respond size is approximately 196 B < x < 220 B ....
- you can use a rest service if your database has your postcode or not. if not you can alert your messega. for postgis you can check out PostGIS  RESTful Web Service Framework [here](http://code.google.com/p/postgis-restful-web-service-framework/).

finally you should check out jQuery MsgBox for your result [here](http://s3.envato.com/files/293712/index.html)...

i hope it helps you...

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you'd be better off validating the input using javascript in the browser before sending the data to the web application.

A quick search for "javascript validate postcode netherlands"  found:

http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=178654

...hope this helps.